# Get all children for a given parent id in array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, iterator, parent-child

I have an array like this:

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'parent_id' => null
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'parent_id' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'parent_id' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'parent_id' => null
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5,
        'parent_id' => 4
    )
);
```

How can i find all the childrens of a given parent_id including all grand children? For example the function will return 2,3 for parent_id 1.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a mistype in this question, or am I just too thick to get it?

If I understand, specifying parent_id 1 could return 2 (the value of the id key in the same array), or 1 (the position of the child array within the parent array). 

I do not see how 3 would be a match with this array. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are totally right in your viewpoint but what i want to get is the 'id' value not array index. And you are right again, if i want to get children of parent_id 1 i will get get id 2. But it's gettin' tricky after that. After finding children of id 1, i dont want to stop and continue to find children of these results too. (sorry for bad english by the way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

// I corrected the array to fit your result 1 => 2,3

```
    <?php

    $test = array(
    array(
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_id' => null
    ),
    array(
            'id' => 2,
            'parent_id' => 1
    ),
    array(
            'id' => 3,
            'parent_id' => 1
    ),
    array(
            'id' => 4,
            'parent_id' => null
    ),
    array(
            'id' => 5,
            'parent_id' => 4
    )
    );

    // 1_2+3
    $parent_childs = ARRAY();
    foreach ($test AS $index => $child) {
        if (!isset($child['parent_id'])) { continue; }
        $parent_childs[$child['parent_id']][] = $child['id'];
    }


    echo '<pre>';var_dump($parent_childs); echo '</pre>';

    ?>
```